# Semantic networks and conceptual graphs

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, semantic-similarity

I would like to use semantic networks to understand changes in texts.
For example when I add/remove some words within a text.

```
I would like to eat pizza tomorrow evening.
I ate pizza yesterday.
```

Or just adding a not before a verb, which changes the text meaning:

```
I would prefer to not eat pizza tomorrow evening.
I didn’t eat pizza yesterday.
```

I have read about the use of word2vec and neural networks to do this, but I would like if anyone has already tried to do something similar.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What kind of semantic network? I'm not aware of anything like this based on neural networks but I don't know everything. This could also be related to non-ML formalisms, such as CCGs, Tree-Adjoining Grammars etc.

Comment: Hi Erwan. I do not know if NN can work with semantic problems. A good read is the following: https://books.google.it/books?hl=en&lr=&id=lTKnCQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=Semantic+Networks+sowa&ots=L_Ov4DhuZJ&sig=Lp6wT8S1fg_tvT0SYphvC0Ae-Ok#v=onepage&q=Semantic%20Networks%20sowa&f=false however, I have seen use of glove and word2vec for similar problems and  would have known if this can be suitable to determine and find changes in text's meaning

Comment: Well it's clear that NN can work with many semantic problems, typically words embeddings are a form of semantic representation. but the question is whether any NN method uses a semantic graph representation of sentences. I don't know  but I feel it's unlikely, because this would require deciding a formal graph representation for the meaning of any sentence, as opposed to the general DL philosophy of leaving the training process determine the internal representation on its own. Again I could be wrong about that.